# display data (taxonomy terms) after uploading it directly to the database

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms, database

I have created a taxonomy vocabulary and then uploaded via mysql all the needed tables for the different fields.

I have created a view where I can see all the terms of the vocabulary, but if I go to `/admin/structure/taxonomy/myvocabulary` I can only see the terms that I have edited and saved, where, which table I have to modify for the terms to be displayed at the vocabulary page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

From what I can tell those are all the taxonomy tables, but none of them seem to contain the term (url) path; thus, they must be in the **url_alias** table. Also, don't forget to flush your cache to see the changes.

I think it's better/safer if you use feeds to import your taxonomy terms.

### [Feeds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihyUR.jpg)

> **Import** or aggregate data as nodes, users, **taxonomy terms** or simple
>   database records.
>
> - One-off imports and periodic aggregation of content
> - Import or aggregate RSS/Atom feeds
> - **Import or aggregate CSV files**
> - Import or aggregate OPML files
> - PubSubHubbub support
> - **Create** nodes, users, **taxonomy terms** or simple database records from import
> - Extensible to import any other kind of content
> - Granular mapping of input elements to Drupal content elements
> - Exportable configurations
> - Batched import for large files

[Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXgjFRn7ty4)

Comment: Thanks @No Sssweat, I had to do some work around, export the fields first, and some other things, but finally reimporting with feeds made the trick.

Comment: Just to clarify, I did export the vocabulary using Views Data Export module (https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export)